# C# - SQLite SELECT Query * Return Data Type

Tags: c#, sqlite

When I query a SQLite Table from C# using an asterisks like:

```
string SQLText = "SELECT * FROM [TableName]";
SqliteCommand Command = new SqliteCommand (SQLText, Database);
(?) Result = (?)Command.ExecuteScalar ();
```

Since there is obviously going to be more than one data value (And Typically of different types) is it returned as an array of Objects "object[]".

What Data Type is being returned? If you find out please post where you got your info so I can avoid asking stupid questions again.

Sean

Comment: What is the type of your first column in that query?

Comment: you should **execute** your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecuteScalar` will return only a single value, the first row/first column of the result set. It is typically used  to retrieve a single value (for example, an aggregate value) from a database, like `COUNT` etc.

You need a collection of records back. Use:

- [SQLiteDataReader](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.html)
- [SQLiteDataAdapter](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter.html) to fill a `DataTable` or `DataSet`

See: [Retrieving data with SqliteDataReader](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitecsharp/read/)

Comment: Ok makes sense thanks, I misread the description of ExecuteScalar() I assumed it returned the entire row.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
command.ExecuteReader();
```

if you want to get more than one rows. `ExecuteScalar()` will return only single value;

`ExecuteScalar()` is only used for queries which are expected to return only single values like
`"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [TableName]"`

You can read about [ExecuteScalar()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [ExecuteReader()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)